# Derive from Control and then allow others to apply a style

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

I have derived a new control from Control base class and set the DefaultStyleKeyProperty in the static constructor so that the appropriate style from Generic.xaml is used to defined the ControlTemplate. This all works fine and I get the expected appearance of several buttons etc.

Now I want to add some Style instances that customize the settings of my new control, such as the font and foreground color. But when I assign the style to the custom controls Style property it seems to remove the original default style and so it no longer has any appearance.

This doesn't seem quite right. The TabControl has a default style but you can still assign a Style to the TabControl.Style property that only modifies the Foreground color and it will not remove the rest of the TabControl appearance in the process.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your new style based on the default:

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type MyControl} BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type MyControl}>
```